# Can a machine be powered with food energy?

Tags: batteries, electricity, energy

Would it be possible, in principle, to create a machine that digests food in a similar way as humans do, extracts energy from the food, and stores it as electrical energy in a battery to power its own function? I understand this might be impractical or inefficient compared to other technologies, but I am just curious to know if it's something that can be done. (Not sure if I should ask here or on Chemistry Stack Exchange, really...)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biomass#Electrochemical_conversion

Comment: You will want to study a cell type called an ***electrocyte***. These store electrical energy which is gathered from food energy. (Electric eel.) I suspect it is still adenosine triphosphate that is the food energy storage molecule. But I'm not sure. You will need to find the "chemical cycle" which transfers energy gathered from the eel's food into the electrocytes which store that energy as electrical storage. Once you've worked that out, you just need a volunteer to have their head replaced with a computer of some kind and you are done.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as the OP speculates, Chemistry would be a far more appropriate site for this question.

Comment: Sounds like you want to make the “flux capacitor” and its power supply.

Comment: Bio-gas plants might be more appropriate.

Comment: This new scientist article would be a good read for you. https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn16882-yeast-powered-fuel-cell-feeds-on-human-blood/ 
I have heard of "batteries" being made from yeast and also algae broths. 
There's a few more interesting articles if you search "yeast battery".  A bio-compatible battery would be a holy grail for all sorts of electronic implants.

Comment: You can run diesel engines on vegetable oil. You can ferment corn syrup to alcohol to run a petrol engine. Both these are done large scale already. So, on one level, yes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar_battery

Answer (score 2):

Here they seem to be working on robots which digest insects:

[Domestic robots with a taste for flesh](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn17372-gallery-domestic-robots-with-a-taste-for-flesh/?ignored=irrelevant)

> But the robots also have a taste for flesh. They can gain energy by chomping on flies and mice, an idea inspired by researchers at Bristol Robotics Lab, UK, who built a fly-powered robot and have also suggested that marine robots could feed on plankton.

> The pests are lured in and digested by an internal microbial fuel cell. This exploits the way microbes generate free electrons and hydrogen ions when oxidising chemicals for energy. Electronics can be powered by directing the electrons around an external circuit before reuniting them with the ions.

Read more: https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn17372-gallery-domestic-robots-with-a-taste-for-flesh/#ixzz6X9vuVDvi